# How to free json_object pointer after each call

Tags: c, json, memory-leaks, segmentation-fault, free

I know that we can use function `json_object_put()` to free the pointer of `struct json_object`. But i have the problem when i try to free the pointer to this struct after each call of the function that declared and used it. The program will be `Segmentation fault (core dumped)` in second iterator of while loop because i use `json_object_put(obj1);` in `test_json` function.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <json-c/json.h>
struct json_object * parse_object;
void init() {

    char buffer_file[] = "{ \"object\": {\"array1\": [1, 2, 3], \"array2\": [4, 5, 6] } }";
    parse_object = json_tokener_parse(buffer_file);

}
void test_json() {
    struct json_object * obj1, * arr1;
    json_object_object_get_ex(parse_object, "object", &obj1);
    json_object_object_get_ex(obj1, "array1", &arr1);
    int size = json_object_array_length(arr1);
    printf("size = %d \n", size);
    json_object_put(obj1);  
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    int j = 0;
    int max = 4;
    init();
    while(++j < max) {
       test_json();
    }
    json_object_put(parse_object);
    return 0;
}
```

I can use just `json_object_put(parse_object);` in main function to free all `json_object` but if i increase the `max` value to be huge (`1000000` for instance), leak-memory will become very much before i call `json_object_put(parse_object);`.

So, in this case, how can free `json_object` (`obj1`) (`parse_object` is always a global variable) ? If it's not possible, please give another solution for getting info from json file in c.

Link for the document of [struct json_object](https://json-c.github.io/json-c/json-c-0.10/doc/html/json__object_8h.html)

Comment: I think that my answer and @mattefrank's one together provide a good analysis of what is going on. If they answer your question accept their answer, rather than mine, because without their answer I wouldn't have had enough info to post mine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How do you actually know that there is leaking memory?
When I run your example with valgrind without using any `json_object_put` the heap summary is always like the following (I ran your code with `max = 4` and `max = 1000000`):

```
==57154== HEAP SUMMARY:
==57154==     in use at exit: 2,949 bytes in 21 blocks
==57154==   total heap usage: 32 allocs, 11 frees, 5,826 bytes allocated
==57154== 
==57154== LEAK SUMMARY:
==57154==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==57154==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==57154==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==57154==    still reachable: 2,949 bytes in 21 blocks
==57154==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==57154== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
```

When I run the example only using `json_object_put(parse_object);` all memory is freed:

```
==57937== HEAP SUMMARY:
==57937==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==57937==   total heap usage: 32 allocs, 32 frees, 5,826 bytes allocated
==57937== 
==57937== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
```

**Note**: I tested with the master branch of the [json-c repository](https://github.com/json-c/json-c)

Also the [json-c documentation](https://json-c.github.io/json-c/json-c-0.10/doc/html/json__object_8h.html#af3f38b3395b1af8e9d3ac73818c3a936) states that **no** reference counts will be changed when calling `json_object_object_get_ex`.

What version do you use? Did you already check the issues on Github?

Comment: Thanks. I tested with valgrind but did not do attention with the difference between 4 and 1000000.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [example page](https://gist.github.com/alan-mushi/19546a0e2c6bd4e059fd) on the GitHub **Json-C** project which documentation, I have to admit, is not very clear, it seems that

```
int json_object_put(struct json_object *jso);
```

is **never** called when the `struct json_object` is obtained through a `json_tokener_parse()` call. It is rather used when it has been obtained through one of these calls

```
jobj = json_object_new_object();
res  = json_object_new_array();
```

This make me think that with

```
int test_json() {
    struct json_object * obj1, * arr1;
    json_object_object_get_ex(parse_object, "object", &obj1);
    /* ... */
    json_object_put(obj1);
    return size;   
}
```

in some way you freed all the allocated memory with `json_object_put(obj1);` because `obj1` was the only one object to be freed and nothing was left in `parse_object`.

My hypothesis is that `json_object_put(obj1);` of all objects obtained with `json_tokener_parse()`, one by one, is alternative to one call to `json_object_put(parse_object);` in the end.

**@mattefrank**'s analysis confirms this hypotesis.

Comment: Yes, that is reason why `segmentation fault`. I forgot to check the number of memories are leaked as the analysis of @mattefrank. Thanks